# Cannot resolve symbol 'OnShowAdCompleteListener'

Tags: java, android, admob

I get error `Cannot resolve symbol 'OnShowAdCompleteListener'`. How can I fix it? This code is form Google's official GitHub AdMob [tutorial](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/3daa6957d32ff0014f33c564e172a48f29fbe1a2/java/admob/AppOpenExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/appopenexample/MyApplication.java#L16). I also added the same imports in my file, so I don't see what is missing, everything else is fine. Thank you for your help. Thank you for your help. Thank you for your help.

```
/**
 * Show the ad if one isn't already showing.
 *
 * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
 * @param onShowAdCompleteListener the listener to be notified when an app open ad is complete
 */
private void showAdIfAvailable(
        @NonNull final Activity activity,
        @NonNull OnShowAdCompleteListener onShowAdCompleteListener) {
    // If the app open ad is already showing, do not show the ad again.
    if (isShowingAd) {
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The app open ad is already showing.");
        return;
    }

    // If the app open ad is not available yet, invoke the callback then load the ad.
    if (!isAdAvailable()) {
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The app open ad is not ready yet.");
        onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
        loadAd(activity);
        return;
    }

    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

    appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
            new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                /** Called when full screen content is dismissed. */
                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                    appOpenAd = null;
                    isShowingAd = false;

                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.");
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
                    loadAd(activity);
                }

                /** Called when fullscreen content failed to show. */
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                    appOpenAd = null;
                    isShowingAd = false;

                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: " + adError.getMessage());
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
                    loadAd(activity);
                }

                /** Called when fullscreen content is shown. */
                @Override
                public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent.");
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    isShowingAd = true;
    appOpenAd.show(activity);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place. **`OnShowAdCompleteListener`** is not an external class so looking at the imports won't change much.

Look at the line number **127** of the **`MyApplication.java`**

```
  public interface OnShowAdCompleteListener {
    void onShowAdComplete();
  }
```

So it seems to be an inner interface inside this class. So you either have to use it in the same way in your own example, or create your own interface and import that